# Workaound for pandas Replace in version 0.24.1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have stumbled accross a Python Pandas bug which was fixed in 0.24.2 ([GH25259](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25259)) for which I am looking for a workaround which works in 0.24.1.

Goal is to **replace** all letters with values.

Python Example Code

```
replace_val = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]
replace_val = pd.DataFrame(replace_val)

rule = [['[a] + [b] + [c]'], 
        ['[b] + [b] + [c]'], 
        ['[a] + [c] + [c]'], 
        ['([a] + [b] + [c])'], 
        ['( [a] + [b] + [c] )']]
rule = pd.DataFrame(rule)

rule_tmp = rule

for index, row in replace_val.iterrows():
    dataid = '\[' + str(row[0] + '\]')
    datavalue = str(row[1])
    rule_tmp.replace({dataid:datavalue}, inplace=True, regex=True)
for n, row in rule_tmp.iterrows():
    print(row[0])
```

output 0.24.1

```
1 + [b] + [c]
2 + 2 + [c]
1 + [c] + [c]
([a] + [b] + [c])
( [a] + [b] + [c] )
```

output 0.25.1

```
1 + 2 + 3
2 + 2 + 3
1 + 3 + 3
(1 + 2 + 3)
( 1 + 2 + 3 )
```

**Does anybody know a workaround to get the results as in pandas version 0.25.1 using a 0.24.1 version?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  pandas `str.translate` with using of python class method `str.maketrans`

```
repl_key, repl_val = replace_val.astype(str).agg(''.join)
repl_ignore = '[]'

rule_tmp = rule[0].str.translate(str.maketrans(repl_key, repl_val, repl_ignore))

Out[182]:
0        1 + 2 + 3
1        2 + 2 + 3
2        1 + 3 + 3
3      (1 + 2 + 3)
4    ( 1 + 2 + 3 )
Name: 0, dtype: object
```